# How do I rotate div to specific coordinates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two (or 3) coordinates.

They are the 2 upper coordinates: left and right

How do I create a div where the left corner has the coordinate of the left one and the right corner the coordinate of the right one.

The rotation should be created from these coordinates or this height difference between these 2 points

How can I achieve this?

Comment: First find the angle you need to rotate. [This page](http://css3please.com/) includes some JS that will calculate the correct CSS to use in different browsers. (Sorry, no time at the moment to put together a complete solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the angle between the two coordinates, you could use `Math.atan2`

```
var angle = Math.atan2(Y2 - Y1, X2 - X1);
```

you could then use a CSS3 property to set the correct angle on the div.